# How to correctly exit a loop in javascript and prevent it from iterating any further?

Tags: javascript, loops, break

I wrote a very simple loop to look for position of dots '.' and spaces in a string then slice it and push them into an array. The loop must end when it finds the last dot. I think I'm making a mistake, since the loop doesn't exit quotes right, and I get double outputs.

Here is the code:

```
var str = '.boom .style #foo .media';
var p = 0;
var className = [];
searchLoop: for(i = 0; i < str.length; i ++) {
    var n = str.indexOf('.', p);
    var o = str.indexOf('#');
    var p = str.indexOf(' ', n) ;
    if(str.indexOf('#') >= 0)
        var idName = str.slice(o + 1, n);
    if(str.lastIndexOf('.') !== n)
        className.push(str.slice(n + 1, p));
    console.log(className);
    console.log(idName);
    if(str.lastIndexOf('.') === n) {
        className.push(str.slice(n + 1, p) + str[str.length - 1]);
        break searchLoop;
    }
}
```

And here is the output:

```
["boom", "style", "media"]
["boom", "style", "media"]
["boom", "style", "media"]
foo
```

I edited the code a bit so it can pick '#' too and this time I get triple results.

Comment: Is there a reason you're implementing this yourself? Don't reinvent the wheel in production code! Use [`String.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)! Reimplementation makes code error-prone; use tried-and-true methods. Don't rely on new implementations; there could be an edge case that could break your code, and the standard versions are optimized for performance and written by professional programmers. In an interpreted language like JS, accessing the interpreter directly is best. The built-in `.split()` method does that.

Comment: Yeah, why are you doing this manually? Here, in one line: `str.match(/\w+/g)`.

Comment: Yes, I Know the split method can split a string and return the result as an array. But first, what if there are multiple separator characters that I want to split the string with, and I want to distinguish say a string split by '.' separator and a string split by a '#' separator, second my question is not how to split a string, it is how to exit a loop.

Comment: You can use regex with split `str.split(/[.#]/)`...

Comment: Your loop is exiting properly. It's just some funky console behavior that delays the evaluation of the Array. Change it to `console.log(className.slice())` and you'll see a difference. Also helpful if you log `i`. You'll see that there are three iterations.

Comment: Are you parsing CSS? It looks like it.

Comment: I recommend using split(). I understand that you want to be able to handle multiple delimiters, but your current code is hard coded to only consider '.' , so the limitations of split apply equally to your current implementation

Comment: @elclanrs that's a good enough answer to split a string with regexp, but how to differentiate between strings that were separated by '#' from strings that were separated by '.' e.g. `str = '.boom #foo .bar'`, the program must know that 'boom' and 'bar' was separated by a '.' but 'foo' was separated by a '#'

Comment: It does look like you're trying to parse CSS... In any case, I'd still suggest a regex, just because you're working with patterns, it is the perfect tool. You can match with `/([.#])(\w+)/` and separate the capture groups into an array of objects like `[{type:'.',text:'boom'},{type:'#',text:'foo'},...]`

Comment: @CrazyTrain you are right, it's just a funky console behavior, it does iterates only three times.

Comment: @elclanrs that's an excellent idea. I might as well try that.

Comment: @MathSquared11235 in the example: `str = '.boom .style #foo .media';` I could simply use `str.split(/[.#]/)` which will give me `["", "boom ", "style ", "foo ", "media"]` which is very mush useless, since there is no way for the code to know which of these are class names and which one is an id name, if `I use str.split(' ');` instead I will get a better result: `[".boom", ".style", "#foo", ".media"]`, however the program still has too loop through this array in order to know which is what!

Comment: Then simply `split` the string on `' '`, then loop through this array. That should be much easier than trying to split the array yourself, since the string is already tokenized. Just go through each array, and if the first character of each is a `.`, add it to the class names, and if the first character is a `#`, add it to the ids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your results 
here is the JSFiddle for your code
http://jsfiddle.net/q34gt/

and here is the output I get in **Chrome**

```
["boom"]
["boom", "style"] 
["boom", "style"] 
foo
```

and this is correct according to your coding logic.

**If you open your console after executing the code you will get the following output**

```
["boom", "style", "media"]
["boom", "style", "media"]
["boom", "style", "media"]
foo
```

**same as you got because the console reads the className after all the three items have been already added to the array.**

**I just tried with mozilla and I was getting same output as yours but rest assured your code is executing as expected and is breaking the loop too. I just replaced your console log with the alert and you get the expected result as explained below and here is the fiddle**
http://jsfiddle.net/q34gt/1/

your className array is being showed on the console for every iteration, after the execution of this particular if statement

```
if(str.lastIndexOf('.') !== n)
        className.push(str.slice(n + 1, p));
```

- on the first iteration after the above if is executed the className array contains [boom]
- on the second iteration after the above if is executed the className array contains [boom, style]
- on the third iteration after the above if is executed the className array contains [boom, style] because str.lastIndexOf('.') !== n condition fails and  className.push(str.slice(n + 1, p)); is not executed

Comment: @igaar does that answer your question, if not let me know if you have any questions

Comment: @igaar I am glad I could help, if it answers your question, can you accept it as an answer by clicking the tick mark.

Answer (score 1):

```
var temp = str.split('.')

for(var i = 1; i < temp.length; i++){
  className.push(temp[i].trim())
}
```

Exiting a loop is done through a simple `break;` Alternatively, you could move the code into a function and exit the loop by doing `return className;` which will break out of the loop as well as the function

However, I have provided an alternative solution above that doesn't require an early exit

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't solve the problem of duplicate results.

Comment: @TGH can I see some reasoning behind behind why you shouldn't `break` with a label, or is it just that this is a simple loop so unnecessary?

Comment: I rewrote the solution, so a break is no longer necessary. Hopefully this is what the OP wants

Answer (score 1):

As MathSquared11235 said, there is no need to reinvent the wheel, however the answer turned out to be not as simple as using just a single and simple split method.

here is how to differentiate between '.' and '#' using RegExp as elclanrs suggested:

```
var str = '.boom .style #foo .media';
var className = str.match(/[.]\w+/g); // match for words that begin with '.'
var idName = str.match(/[#]\w+/g); // match for words that being with '#'
className = className.join(''); // join all items so we have a string to play with
className = className.replace(/[.]/g,' '); // replace all '.' with ' '
className = className.replace(' ', ''); // remove the first ' '
className = className.split(' '); // split the className using ' ' separator so we have an array again. 
idName = idName.toString(); // make it a string
idName = idName.replace('#',''); // just remove the '#'
console.log(className);
console.log(idName);
```

end this would be the output:

```
["boom", "style", "media"]
foo
```

another way to do this is:

```
var str = '.boom .style #foo .media';
var cssSelectors = str.split(' ');
var className = [];
searchLoop: for(i = 0; i < cssSelectors.length; i ++) {
if(cssSelectors[i].indexOf('#') > -1 && cssSelectors[i] && cssSelectors[i] !== '#')
    var idName = cssSelectors[i].replace('#', ''); // just to make it foolproof and make sure no empty string and stand alone '#' pass through
if(cssSelectors[i].indexOf('.') > -1 && cssSelectors[i] && cssSelectors[i] !== '.')
    className.push(cssSelectors[i].replace('.', '')); // no '' and no stand alone '.' can pass through
console.log(className);
console.log(idName);
}
```

and the output will be:

```
["boom", "style", "media"]
foo
["boom", "style", "media"]
foo
["boom", "style", "media"]
foo
["boom", "style", "media"]
foo
```